# scikit-learn: Estimating an output value from a set of input values (trained via existing data)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Say I have this input data:

```
[[1.0, 1.5, 2.0],
 [2.0, 1.5, 2.0],
 [1.0, 2.0, 3.0],
 [1.0, 1.5, 3.0]]
```

And this output data:

```
[100, 100, 80, 60]
```

Assuming the input values have no predetermined correlation, how can I use scikit-learn to use this data to estimate an output value from a set of input values?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any scikit-learn regression model to predict output for next set of features. Please go through scikit-learn documentation. To get you started,

```
In [1]: from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

In [2]: xtr = [[1.0, 1.5, 2.0],
   ...:  [2.0, 1.5, 2.0],
   ...:  [1.0, 2.0, 3.0],
   ...:  [1.0, 1.5, 3.0]]

In [3]: ytr = [100, 100, 80, 60]

In [4]: lr = LinearRegression()

In [5]: lr.fit(xtr, ytr)
Out[5]: LinearRegression(copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, n_jobs=1, normalize=False)

In [6]: lr.predict([1.0, 2.5, 1.5])
Out[6]: array([ 160.])
```